# Using a REST proxy in ExtJS doesn't seem to post any data

Tags: php, ajax, post, extjs

I'm using this ExtJS REST proxy to get and post data to my REST back end

```
this.eventStore = Ext.create('Extensible.calendar.data.EventStore', {
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'http://www.notmyrealdomain/testapp/index.php/api/events',
        format: 'json',
        noCache: false,

        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        },

        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            nameProperty: 'mapping'
        }            
    }
}
```

When I do a print_r on the PHP receiving end it looks like $_POST is empty

```
print_r($_POST)
array()
```

When I look at Firebug I see that my API page does have JSON being posted to it but the response is just the empty $_POST array.

I have checked my config.php BASE_URL and it is my full url http://www.notmyrealdomain.com/testapp
and I'm pretty sure my proxy above is posting to that url, it's not returning 404 and it doesn't look like it would be cross domain or anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
I've been looking at this for 8 hours now and need some new eyes.

Help me stackoverflow, your my only hope.

Comment: You sure it's not a GET instead of a POST?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not doing a GET. $_GET returns an empty array just like $_POST, it's a REST proxy so it's supposed to be doing a GET or POST as appropriate and I do GET data back from the REST API when that's what I'm requesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It send by PUT method.

In PHP try:

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are using full "http://..." URL. If your REST service is on a different domain you need a JSONP proxy.